# Game Center Achievements and Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, gamekit

I have a singleton class that handles all my game center stuff. I have set it to be a delegate of GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate.

I call the following method showAchievements

```
 - (void) showAchievements
 {
     GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [[GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
     if (achievements != nil)
     {
         achievements.achievementDelegate = self.delegate;
         [self.viewController presentModalViewController: achievements animated: YES];
     }
 }
```

and I implement the following

```
 - (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)achievements
 {
     [self.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
 }
```

I set self.viewController with the following code before calling showAchievements

```
 AppController* appDelegate = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [GameCenterManager instance].viewController = appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
```

The app crashes and the following shows up in the console log when I call showAchievements.

```
Jul 16 12:36:28 imac-3 myApp[17103] <Info>: 12:36:28.287698 com.apple.AVConference: GKSConnSettings: set server: {
    "gk-cdx" = "17.173.254.218:4398";
    "gk-commnat-cohort" = "17.173.254.220:16386";
    "gk-commnat-main0" = "17.173.254.219:16384";
    "gk-commnat-main1" = "17.173.254.219:16385";
}
```

At the point where I call showAchievements the user has been logged in successfully.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: and where does cocos2d come into this?

Comment: It might be relevant. How I'm getting the root view controller is the only place I can think the issue might be because the other code is pretty much cut and paste from the apple docs. Anyone familiar with the view structure in cocos2d might be able to point out my error. At the same time it might be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicions were correct, I was trying to access the viewController in the wrong way. I should have been using the CCDirectorIOS object instead of the UIWindow object.

Answer (score 0):

GKAchievementViewController is deprecated. Try using GKGameCenterViewController.